# Change div class with PHP after failed authentication?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm setting up a little login script which is working fine. But after failed login, i want a header location change to login.php and erase a class from a div, so its shown up. (Error message of failed login).

The same i want to build after login, with header location change to dashboard.php and there should also erase a div class to show this element.

(The want to delete class giving css value display none).

The header location rewrite is no problem and working. But i dont know how i can realize the erasing div class.

---

Okay on my login.php site i have the following div at the right place:

```
<div id="fail-info" class="w3-panel w3-red w3-hide">
  Your username or password is wrong. Please try it again.
</div>
```

Thats the right part for it from my auth path:

```
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: ../dashboard.php");
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">#login-info{
            display:block;
            }</style>
        <?php
    } else {
        header("Location: ../login.php");
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">#fail-info{
            display:block;
            }</style>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">#fail-info{
        display:block;
        }</style>
    <?php
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: It is not possible to determine anything here because you haven't shown any code and that fails to meet the requirements for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to read the help center, then [edit] your question, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please can you share some of the code so we can assist you for code you've already tried

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['error'])){
...<div class="">Login Failed</div>...
}
?>
```